# ggplot doesn't plot two geom in one figure R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

I try to plot both `geom_histogram` and `geom_density` in one figure. When I plot the two separate from each other I get for each the output I want (histogram and density plot) but when I try combining them, only the histogram is showed (regardless of which order of the histogram/density in the code).

My code looks like this:

```
ggplot(data=Stack_time, aes(x=values))+geom_density(alpha=0.2, fill="#FF6666")+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 50, colour="black", fill="#009454")
```

I do not receive any error message, but the `geom_density` is never shown in combination with the `geom_histogram`.

Comment: please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You question can be solved a lot easier with information about your database

Comment: also my guess: Your data is not normalized. Density plots have an y axis from 0-1, if your data is much higher, the density plot is far to tiny, also add `alpha=0.5` to your `geom_histogram`

Comment: You are right. The density plot is much too small on the y-axis to be visible. Thank you for this clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any data here a solution based on mtcars:

Your code is nearly correct. You need to add an `alpha` value to your histogram, so you can see the density. But also you need to scale your data, since the density plot is between the range of 0 and 1. If you got data values larger then 1, the density plot can be tiny and you can't see it. With the function `scale_data` as defined as follows, i scale my data to the range of 0-1

```
df=mtcars
scale_data <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
df$mpg2 <- scale_data(df$mpg)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=mpg2))+geom_density(alpha=0.2, fill="#FF6666")+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 50, colour="black", fill="#009454", alpha = 0.1)
```

this gives the expected output:
[image: plot]

you can adjust this solution to your needs. Just scale the data or the density plot to the data

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, approximately:

`data.frame(x=rnorm(1000)) %>% ggplot(aes(x, ..density..)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2, alpha=0.5) + geom_density(fill="red", alpha=0.2)`